# How to use access tokens with Google Admin API for GA4 properties?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

With the release of GA4, from reading it seems there is a new API client that we must use to manage GA4 accounts and properties. I am working with PHP and talking about this client: https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-admin

For Google UA (v3), the API allowed us to use OAuth access tokens so that users can grant an application access to their UA accounts. Now, with the new GA4 Admin API, it allows us to add service credentials but I can't see how I can use OAuth access tokens?

For example here is my PHP code:

```php
$ga4 = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['credentials' => $cred]);

    $accounts = $ga4->listAccounts();

    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
        print 'Found account: ' . $account->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

The passed in `$cred` variable is just a decoded `keyFile` array. But that does not accept an OAuth token?

With the v3 Analytics API, it was so simple, you were able to create a new Google Client like this and pass an access token:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($keyFile);
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
```

And then that new client could be passed to the Analytics client...

So with the new GA4 API, how do I set an access token obtained from OAuth setup with a user that grants permissions for me to access their GA account?

Comment: Sadly they are only documenting service account authorization.  Are you looking for native or web client auth?

Comment: @DaImTo I am looking to implement this over the web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out. You have to call `\Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::build` to create a credentials object. Which you then use to authenticate with a refreshed OAuth token.

```
$credentials = \Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper::build([
    'keyFile' => $keyFile,
    'scopes'  => [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    ]
]);
```

Then the `$keyFile` needs to be changed to not be a service account but an `authorized_user`:

```
$keyFile = [
    'type'          => 'authorized_user',
    'client_id'     => <YOUR_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CLIENT_ID>,
    'client_secret' => <YOUR_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CLIENT_SECRET>,
    'refresh_token' => $accessToken
];
```

Then you can pass it to a new GA4 object like so:

`$ga4Client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['credentials' => $credentialsd]);`

A little different compared to how the UA client works.